# How to lowercase all keys in json dict with Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, lowercase

I am new to this site so be gentle to me, no homo.

I'm currently practicing my Python skills with code that checks given key against JSON dictionary and gives you the definition of key.
Now I know there are other solutions to my issue, but I'm trying to figure out this one specifically if it's possible.

I'm trying to change all keys in my dictionary to lowercase, and I'm trying it like this for now:

```
data = json.load(open("data.json"))

for key in data.keys():
    key = key.lower()
```

What this dictionary file looks like (example of one key):

```
"act": ["Something done voluntarily by a person, and of such a nature that certain legal consequences attach to it.", "Legal documents, decrees, edicts, laws, judgments, etc.", "To do something.", "To perform a theatrical role."]
```

Apparently it has more than one value per key which creates problem when trying other solutions.

Comment: `key = key.lower()` just assigns the new, lowercase `str` object to the local variable `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
data = json.load(open("data.json"))
new_data = {key.lower():value for key, value in data.items()}
```

And then you can replace the old data with the new one.

```
with open("data.json") as fp:
    json.dump(new_data, fp)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! I already tried making new_data variable as you have shown, but it didn't work properly, this was the one I was using: new_data = dict((key.lower(), value) for key, value in data.keys()). Something wrong there I guess, but thank you for showing the proper way to do it!

Comment: @AdiKešetović that did not work because you were trying to get only keys and not the items which give key-value pair. That should have been: new_data = dict((key.lower(), value) for key, value in a.items())

Comment: @srahul07 I tried your solution and that works too! Thank you for explaining the error, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @bumblebee is correct and smallest. But if you have difficulty in understanding that dictionary comprehension refer following code (I't same as @bumblebee's code)

```py
data = json.load(open("data.json"))
new_data = {}
for key, value in data.items():
    new_data[key.lower()] = value

# any code if you want to add further

with open("data.json") as fp:
    json.dump(new_data, fp)
```